# Вывод JSON данных из mysql через php

Tags: php, mysql, json

В "mysql" базе есть поле с типом "json" (MySQL 5.7). "PHP" категорически отказывается выводить это самое поле, при этом, если банально убрать это поле из выборки - все нормально. Также пробовал выполнить запрос в "phpmyadmin" - все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Подключение "PHP":

```
mysql_select_db("datas" ,$db);
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM test',$db);
echo '<pre>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        print_r ($row);
}
echo '</pre>';
mysql_close($db);
```

Подключение PHP с помощью mysqli:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM test');
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row){
    print_r ($row);
}
echo '</pre>';
```

В обоих случаях все работает, если убрать из выборки поле json.

Отдельно по запросам:

- не работает:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM test
  ```
- не работает:

  ```
  SELECT jsondata FROM test
  ```
- не работает:

  ```
  SELECT id,name,jsondata FROM test
  ```
- работает:

  ```
  SELECT id,name FROM test
  ```

Версия php: 5.3.29

Версия mysql: 5.7.13

Answer (score 0):

Ситуацию удалось воспроизвести. Если есть возможность воспользоваться альтернативным расширением PDO, я бы предложил воспользоваться им - он JSON-данные обрабатывает корректно.

```
try {
  $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'root',
    '',
    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

  $query = "SELECT * FROM test";
  $cat = $pdo->query($query);

  $results = $cat->fetchAll();
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($results);
  echo '</pre>';    
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Попробовал Ваш пример, в итоге появляется ошибка:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Если вставить json поле